# When does merge into current branch from Intelij compares 2 branches in 2 way direction?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, merge, git-merge

So I am a bit confused here and need some clarification. I can not fully describe all the commits and workflow but it is something like the following picture

[image]

On the final commit I am on branch `release-2.0.0` and use Intelij to make merge into current branch from branch `featureB`

I receive a text then that says

```
no merged conflicts
> changes to commit c23 -> a number of files
> changes to commit b 12 -> a number of files
```

Considering that I merge feature B branch into release-2.0.0, the text `changes to commit b 12 -> a number of files` makes sense to me. However the other text `changes to commit c23` does not make any sense.

The actual git structure is much more complex. I can not describe it analytically. I am trying to understand however in what cases the merge produces this result and why?

Any info would be appreciated

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ so I can't speak for it in the first place, but I'll note that if you can't describe the problem, it's going to be hard for anyone else to describe the solution. :-) There's one obvious *Git* answer to a similar question, but unless you're asking *that* question about *Git* (rather than this one about a different program doing something different), I don't think I should answer it.

Comment: A shorter or better way to put this might be: work on your question first, so that you have something really solid for someone to answer.

Comment: What is the process in git that has a similar result?

Comment: You can run `git show -m` on a merge commit (or run two separate `git diff` commands, one to each parent) and get two diffs.

Answer (score 1):

A regular commit introduces some changes against its parent, and it has only one parent, and it is clear when browsing changes of the commit. But a merge commit has several (two in the example) parents, and the content saved in the merge commit can differ from any (or all) parents. This is sometimes useful to know what those changes are.

By default `git show` for a merge commit will not show those changes and only list files that required conflict resolution. But you can call `git show -m` to see diffs against all parents.

IntelliJ tries to make the changes in commit clearer and shows this information in the changes browser. If you do not want to see this, disable the **Show Changes to Parents** option in the context menu.